# OpenGL coloured bitmap font with white outline

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

I've got a libgdx game where I want to use a bitmap font with an outline. I want to be able to set the font colour using setColor(), however, I always want the outline to remain white. What's the best way for me to achieve this? I'm assuming I should do the required colour manipulation using the fragment shader.

I've created a bitmap font as below, with red representing the stroke and green representing the set colour.

[image]

I'm a little stuck with what I need to do in the fragment shader however. My experience and understanding of shaders is limited. My current shader looks like this, which draws the stroke correctly based on the r. I'm not sure how I should be adding in the set colour (v_color) to colour the middle of the font correctly.

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
  vec4 textureColour = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
  vec4 colour = vec4(textureColour.r,
                textureColour.r,
                textureColour.r,
                textureColour.a);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(colour.r, colour.g, colour.b, colour.a);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way you defined your font image, the amount of red determines how much of the outline color to use, and the amount of green determines how much of the inside color to use. So after you sample the texture, you can simply calculate the weighted average of the outline color and inside color, with the `r` of the sampled texture being the weight of the outline color, and `g` being the weight of the inside color.

The calculation in the shader can be simplified further because your outline color is a fixed white. So `r` multiplied by the outline color is just a vector with `r` for all it's components:

```
r * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) = vec4(r, r, r, r) = vec4(r)
```

Using the `v_color` varying for the inside color, the fragment shader will then look like this:

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 texVal = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    gl_FragColor = texVal.g * v_color + texVal.r;
}
```

This will work if the `r` and `g` component of the texture are zero for the parts that are outside the letters. If the outside is not black, but the `a` component of the texture is used to mask them out, the expression becomes slightly more complicated:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 texVal = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texVal.g * v_color.rgb + texVal.r, texVal.a);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It's drawing in the areas that are 100% transparent. If I add gl_FragColor.a = texVal.a at the end it works. I don't know if that could be incorporated more elegantly as my understanding of vector arithmetic in shaders is limited.

Comment: Ah, ok, your question didn't specify that you were using blending. Let me see how I can incorporate that.

Comment: Well, I think this would work as is if the parts of the texture outside the letters were black. But it sounds like they might be non-black with alpha = 0.

Comment: Updated with alternate version that uses alpha of texture.

Answer (score 1):

Aslong your texture-colors are made up by those two RGB-colors: red:#ff0000 and green:#00ff00
like they are in your image, you could use the following shader

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
  vec4 textureColour = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
  // normalizing the values
  float rgsum = textureColour.r + textureColour.g;
  float pr = textureColour.r / rgsum;
  float pg = textureColour.g / rgsum;
  // setting the color of the fragment
  gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(1.0) * pr + v_color.rgb * pg, textureColour.a * v_color.a);
}
```

---

Oh and btw: very confusing your mixture of BE and AE, you should use color (<s>or colour</s>) only.

Comment: Thanks for that. If you could point me in the right direction on the next step of my problem that'd be great. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972751/whats-causing-the-dark-borders-around-letters-using-opengl