# What's causing the dark borders around letters using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969727/opengl-coloured-bitmap-font-with-white-outline).

When I draw the letters I'm getting a dark border around some areas. Below is an example zoomed 4x. The letter on the left is drawn with OpenGL. The letter on the right is my bitmap font atlas in Photoshop colour adjusted to match what is being drawn by my game. As you can see, the 's' on the left has noticeable dark borders in some areas.

[image]

I've played with various blending options but can't work out what's causing it. If someone could tell me what the cause is and how to fix it that's be appreciated.

Comment: This problem relates to premultiplied and non-premultiplied alpha in images with transparency.Maybe this links help you out a little: http://programming4.us/multimedia/2870.aspx http://www.gamedev.net/topic/623481-how-to-create-pre-multiplied-alpha-for-use-with-opengl/ also search for "openGL premultiplied alpha"